# How to pick Export Compliance in my app?

Tags: ios, cryptography, submit, app-store-connect, facebook-login

I am submitting for review and not sure about the `Export Compliance`question `Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or macOS.)` The only internet function in my app is using `Facebook Login`on first screen for users to register and login. And I use `Firebase` as backend. So do I need to select `Yes`?

If I should pick `Yes` for first question, then second question `Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?` I should also pick `Yes`, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the only use is an https connection to Facebook I would answer no. At WWDC16 I specifically asked this question twice of the security team and was told that they did not consider HTTPS to be encryption for this question.

More:

New U.S. legislation went into effect on September 20th, 2016. The new regulation removes the requirement to register your app simply because it uses encryption.

Some links to the 2016-09-20 changes: Changes to BIS's information security controls bring relaxed controls, removal of registration requirement [Dentons](http://www.dentons.com/en/insights/alerts/2016/september/30/changes-to-bis-information-security-controls), US Implements Regulation Changes for Encryption Products, Software and Technology [Shadden](https://www.skadden.com/insights/us-implements-regulation-changes-encryption-products-software-and-technology), Export Administration Regulation (EAR) [BIS](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/regulations/export-administration-regulations-ear).

Note that other countries also have regulations covering sale of encryption including France.

How this affects answering the Apple question is unclear. If my app used encryption directly (my API calls directly to AES for example) I would answer "yes" and supply the above information.

Disclaimer: This is not legal advice.

Comment: Hi zaph, thanks for your information. How would this question affect my app if I pick the wrong answer?

Comment: I have no idea how Apple would respond.

Comment: Hi zaph, is Firebase a factor to consider?

Comment: You would have to ask Firebase.

Comment: Hi zaph, thanks for your information. I adopted your answer and my app has been approved.

Comment: @developermike so with Firebase you answered No? I interesting in this question so much atm

Comment: Hi, Apple documentation says otherwise that HTTPS IS included: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9