# Does my app use crypting? Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cryptography, app-store, appstore-approval

I use Firebase database, storage etc. in my application. When I uploaded my archive to Itunes Connect, it has asked me a questions about crypting. Do I use crypting in my application and etc.

I know, that Firebase uses `https`.

So the question is: If I use Firebase, what should I answer on this questions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pick Export Compliance in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235468/how-to-pick-export-compliance-in-my-app)

Comment: @the4kman read the answer: "Disclaimer: This is not legal advice." before the reporting for duplicate. + no info about firebase. We can just guess from this answer. Btw its already uparrowed by mе. But this answer is not enought for me cz it is not exact. Thanks.

Comment: @VladPulichev So, does your app crypting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: @VladPulichev did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

As of September 20th, 2016 ([Dentons](http://www.dentons.com/en/insights/alerts/2016/september/30/changes-to-bis-information-security-controls)) the answer is almost always **No**.  Unless you are a encrypted message provider like Signal, Telegram, Whatsapp or Snapchat - these export controls are no longer a concern.  Nearly every app uses HTTPS these days and it defeats the purpose of the U.S. Export Registry if every app needs to be registered.

The countries that are export restricted are people you don't normally want as customers; Syria, North Korea ect... and are typically restricted from using apps for more fundamental reasons - like not having cellphone towers or even the ability to buy a cellphone.  It is common for backend services like Firebase and Google to blacklist export-restricted IP spaces, so they won't be able to connect even if they get the app.